# Advanced Search Form with Autocomplete

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I want to create an advanced search button that is connected to a dialogue form that searches for a specific criteria. When the user enters the criteria they don't have to press anything the matches just come up something like the following, where the original form has a advanced search button
[image: Original Form]
Which then goes on to produce a connected form that shows the criteria and related records according to the letters of first and last names of the people in the database.
[image: Pop up dialogue form]

Comment: Is there a question mark in the post?... Please note your solution idea, then you could point out a more specific question

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Is there a question or a problem you're having?

Comment: Yes I want to know specifically how to create another form like that that is in image 2 that holds the data I need and allows a user to search for a record. I need to know how to do this using a search for form and a macro? I'm really new to access

Answer (score 0):

Look at the key press event in the form. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194937.aspx. You can react to that event and re-run your query, then update your results on the form.